# Experiment preparation - Box to reduce background photons noise

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, noise

I am planning to perform experiment with a photomultiplier tube (PMT) in my lab. The system is not large, with a length scale of about 10 cm. I am looking to reduce the background photons noise as much as I can, and for this I thought to perform the experiment inside a box of the above length scale. Does anyone here have recommendations for a box that can do that job? I was looking at Amazon/Ebay/Alli express, but there are so many options, so I thought asking another people would be beneficial.

*My budget are flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a "Pelican box" or similar black and waterproof cases. Works perfectly.